# Setting default values of Shared Preferences when using x Preference Fragments

Tags: android, preferences, default-value, fragment, preferenceactivity

I have a bit of confusion about setting default values of shared preferences... for example, I have a *PreferenceActivity* with two or more *PreferenceFragment* and each of the preference fragmens has its own *preference_fragmentX.xml* file used to build the preference view. When I set the default values with

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.?????, false);
```

Which XML should I specify? Should I build another XML preference file containing all the preferences of the *preference_fragmentX.xml* files with the default values and use this one in *setDefaultValues*? For example, I may build an app that registers for a broadcast event and I'm not sure the user opens the preference activity before the broadcast event is fired for the first time, so I'd like to initialize default preferences in the broadcast event, or in another activity started by it.. so, how do I initialize all the preferences of all the fragment panes?

It works if I build a default_preferences.xml file which contains all the preference keys defined in all the preference fragments XML files (I specify only the a *PreferenceScreen* root tag and all the preference tags under it, without specifying all the other tags like *PreferenceCategory*.. furthermore for each preference I specify only the key and the default vale attributes), but I don't know if it is the correct way to do this task, since I must replicate part of the other XML files:

**preferences_fragment1.xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/my_preference_category">
            <RingtonePreference    
                android:key="preference_ringtone"
                android:ringtoneType="alarm|notification"
                android:showSilent="true"
                android:summary="@string/preference_ringtone_summary"
                android:title="@string/preference_ringtone_title" />
    <ListPreference
        android:key="preference_list"
        android:entries="@array/list_items"
        android:entryValues="@array/list_values"
                android:summary="@string/preference_list_summary"
                android:title="@string/preference_list_title" />          
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**default_preference.xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RingtonePreference
        android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
        android:key="preference_ringtone"/>
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="5"                    
        android:key="preference_list"/>          
</PreferenceScreen>
```